# How to find utf8_string in another utf8_string using tinyutf8 in C++11?

Tags: c++, string, c++11, unicode, utf-8

I am using tinyutf8 C++ UTF-8 string library from
https://github.com/DuffsDevice/tinyutf8

I'm trying to call `utf8_string::find_first_of` passing a utf8_string as the first parameter.

This generates the following error:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘utf8_string::find_first_of(utf8_string&, int&)’
int found_pos = haystack.find_first_of(needle, at_pos);
^
In file included from Phonemizer.cpp:8:0:
tinyutf8.h:1728:12: note: candidate: utf8_string::size_type utf8_string::find_first_of(const value_type*, utf8_string::size_type) const
size_type find_first_of( const value_type* str , size_type start_codepoint = 0 ) const ;
^~~~~~~~~~~~~
tinyutf8.h:1728:12: note: no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘utf8_string’ to ‘const value_type* {aka const char32_t*}’
```

How can I get a `char32_t*` from my `utf8_string`?
Alternatively, what other mechanism is there to find a `utf8_string` within another `utf8_string`?

Thanks!
Shawn

Comment: If you're not particular you can just search for the byte sequence. The standard library has lots of find functions. If you're particular you'll have to use a library to convert both search string and text to search in to a canonical form for Unicode, to ensure that characters like "é" (for example) are represented as the same sequence of code points.

Comment: Thanks @Alf for the helpful comment. I started down the path of doing the byte sequence search, getting a raw iterator and working back to a codepoint index but then I realized I could use find instead of find_first_of which accepts a utf8_string parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Shawn, currently tiny_utf8 does not support `find_first_of` with a `utf8_string` as argument. However, to answer your second question: You can convert a `utf8_string` to a `char32_t[]` using `utf8_string::to_wide_literal( &char32_buffer )`.

I hope this helps at least a little bit (even though you said you fixed the problem yourself already, which I am glad to hear :D).

All the best,
Jakob